# How to run a cypress test multiple times one after another?

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, cypress

I am creating a monopoly(a board game played with dice) using react. I have made the rolling system for the game. Now I want to test that.

There are two buttons in my game

- **Roll Button**:

  - Its initially enabled
  - When user clicks it the dices are rolled. Piece of player moves
  - Now there are two cases

    - If doubles are rolled then player gets another turn to roll and this button stays enabled
    - If doubles are not rolled this becomes disabled and other one becomes enabled.
- **End turn button:**

  - Initially its disabled.
  - If die is rolled and doubles are not rolled then this one becomes enabled.
  - When we click this turn changes and for new turn this becomes disabled and roll button becomes enabled again.

Now I am using cypress to test this. I have written the test and it works for fine but just for 1 time. When I use a loop to run the test multiple time it fails

```
describe("Rolling System", function () {
   //The required test
   it("disables button correctly", function () {

      //Visits the page
      cy.visit("localhost:3000").then(() => {

         //A variable which tell if doubles were rolled at last roll or not 
         let isRollDisabled = false;
         for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            //If roll is over then end the turn
            if (isRollDisabled) {
               cy.get(".btn-end-turn").click();
            }

            //If roll button is enabled then click it.
            else {
               console.log(isRollDisabled);

               //Get and click button
               cy.get(".btn-roll")
                  .click()
                  .then((x) => {

                     //Get the dice elements
                     cy.get(".dice").then((dices) => {

                        //Get the rolls of both die
                        let roll1 = dices[0].children.length;
                        let roll2 = dices[1].children.length;

                        //If not doubles
                        if (roll1 !== roll2) {
                           cy.get(".btn-roll").should("be.disabled");
                           console.log("roll disabled changed");
                           isRollDisabled = true;
                        } 

                        //If doubles are rolled
                        else {
                           cy.get(".btn-roll").should("not.be.disabled");
                           isRollDisabled = false;
                        }
                     });
                  });
            }
         }
      });
   });
});
```

Notice the two logs in above code `console.log(isRollDisabled);` and `console.log("roll disabled changed");`

In the log I see that `false` is logged `10` times and then after that `"roll disabled change"` is logged.

I think I have make code such that one test runs after another but I can't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the loops from inside the test body and use [cypress-repeat](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-repeat) from command line instead.